# Bad receiver type 'double'

Tags: objective-c

I know that this has been asked before but I have gone through some of the previous questions and I cannot relate them to my problem.

I'm trying to develop a class in my application that will handle all of the calculations to be performed but I am having a problem with one of the more simple method calls trying to return a double value. I am pretty new to iOS coding so it is probably something simple that I am doing wrong. Anyway here is the code

P.S. I'm not sure if I have given enough information so if I need to add anything else let me know

from the .m file making the method call

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // print the location to the device logs to aid in debugging
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    //this is the problem line here
    //Problem solved thans to trojanfoe and H2CO3
    double currentSpeed = [[BIDCalculations calculateSpeed: newLocation] doubleValue];

    //the problem line was replace with this new line which solved the error
    double currentSpeed = [BIDCalculations calculateSpeed: newLocation];


    // if there is a location to report, print it to the screen
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        _positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f, %.3f",
                               currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                               currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    }
}
```

from the .m file where the method is located (the calculations class)

```
@implementation BIDCalculations

+ (double)calculateSpeed:(CLLocation *)newLocation;
{
    return newLocation.speed;
}
```

from the .h file for the calculations class

```
@interface BIDCalculations : NSObject

+ (double)calculateSpeed:(CLLocation *)newLocation;

@end
```

Comment: If `calculateSpeed:` is already returning a double, why putting `doubleValue`at the end?

Comment: Please learn the language basics before trying to do complicated tasks! If you don't even have an idea about syntax, then how could you possibly make sense of semantics?

Comment: I didn't initially have that in there, but if I leave it out it gives me an error that its returning an incompatible type. Having that piece of code got rid of the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is already returning a `double` so change the problem line to:

```
double currentSpeed = [BIDCalculations calculateSpeed:newLocation];
```

Comment: I tried that but I get an error saying that its returning an incompatible type

Comment: @Ian I don't see why that would be with the code you have posted.

Comment: Neither do I but I'll try it again to double check anyway. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Ian If it still doesn't work, you'll have to re-post the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (double)calculateSpeed:(CLLocation *)newLocation
```

That method already returns a `double`.

```
double currentSpeed = [BIDCalculations calculateSpeed:newLocation];
```

is enough.

Comment: Any reason for removing the upvote? You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Agreed.  I'm a little confused about why the OP cannot see that our answers are identical, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry that reply was to the wrong question sorry. Currently replying off my phone. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yeah you guys were right, I had added in doubleValue before I had fixed another error with the same line of code. Once I fixed that error I guess that value caused the current error. I'll be accepting trojanfoe's answer as he replied first. Thank you both for your input