# Sort numbers inside an array of custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874256/sorting-number-using-nssortdescriptor), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343140/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-containing-numbers-as-strings-in-descending-order) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160039/bad-receiver-type-double) link

I have an array (Say **personObjectArray**) which contains objects of class **Person**.

Class **Person** having 2 variables say, 
`NSString *name, NSString *age`.

Here **age** has type of nsstring.

Now when i sort like below,

```
personObjectArray = [[personObjectArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2){

    return [p1.age compare:p2.age];

}] mutableCopy];
```

It sorts like this,

1,
11,
123
2,
23,
3...  It sorts like alphabetical order not considering it as an number.

So i change my code like this,

```
personObjectArray = [[personObjectArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2){

    return [[p1.age intValue] compare:[p2.age intValue] ];

}] mutableCopy];
```

And it says, `Bad receiver type 'int'`

How can i sort now ? 
Please don't tell me to change the datatype of **age** in **Person** class. I can't change it. Any help appreciated (: , Thanks for the time.

Comment: did you tried compare method instead of using blocks ?

Comment: what's that, can you tell me clearly?

Comment: Map it to type Int, sort it, then map it again to type NSString

Comment: @TheoK Am sorry , how to do that ?

Comment: `return [p1.age compare:p2.age options:NSNumericSearch];` or `return [@([p1.age intValue]) compare:@([p2.age intValue]) ];`

Comment: I am using Swift so you will have to find something similar in Objective-C but the idea is the following:

`var age = ["2", "32", "3", "30"]`

`print(age.flatMap({ Int($0) }).sorted(by: <).map({ String($0) }))`

Result: `["2", "3", "30", "32"]`

Comment: @Larme that's nice.. could you tell me what '@()' will exactly do. I am curious about it

Comment: Check this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343140/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-containing-numbers-as-strings-in-descending-order?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You were using `compare:` on primitive (`int`), thing you can't do, that's why you were getting your error. You have to use `NSNumber` which have a `compare:` method, and `@()` is the short syntax for it. Else, you'll need to do `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:[p1.age intValue]] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[p2.age intValue]]]` which is the same.

Comment: @Larme OMG Yeah, I can clearly understand now. Thanks mate.. !! You saved my time (;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort NSArray of custom objects by a specific property in descending order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217072/how-to-sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-by-a-specific-property-in-descending-order)

Comment: Also, note that since `personObjectArray` is a `NSMutableArray`, use `sortUsingComparator:` instead of `sortedArrayUsingComparator`, and you won't need also the `mutableCopy` and the `return`. Just `[personObjectArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2){...}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using compare on a primitive (Not Object) type `int` , hence it won't work.

Try this

```
 return [@([p1.age intValue]) compare:@([p2.age intValue])];
```

Here, we are using NSNumber (Which is an object type) to compare the int values

> @() is a NSNumber's literal

Hope this will help you.. (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
personObjectArray = [[personObjectArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Person *p1, Person *p2){
    return [p1.age compare:p2.age options:NSNumericSearch];
}] mutableCopy];
```